# Debugging Uglified javascript in production environment

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify, compression

I'm new to AngularJS and Grunt. I have two grunt tasks setup in GruntFile.js for dev and production. For production I'm uglifying & combine many js files into one.

I need some guidance/tips on how to debug uglified javascript code in production if any problem arises. I tried googling asking my co-workers but no help hence my question here on stack-overflow.

Is there a way to un-unglify scripts in production on the fly to debug **or** 
some configuration that toggles to use uncompressed files for debugging and compress files after the job is done.

*You guys gave me some amazing approaches. Thanks*

If there are some more ways kindly please do share.

Comment: Some ideas involving Chrome pretty print, source maps etc at http://www.zsoltnagy.eu/javascript-debugging-tips-and-tricks/. Another option might be for the production system to actually serve up original JS source files if it recognizes you as an insider, e.g. through some special cookie or HTTP header or client source IP range.

Comment: Awesome! thanks for the link jarmond. 
'production system to serve up original JS source files, if it recognizes you as an insider' - this is what i want to achieve. 

can you please throw some more light into it about how can i use 'special cookie or HTTP header to load original js files' or perhaps some links to the use case. Meanwhile I'll also look for ways to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't debug minified code without [source maps](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/).  You'll go crazy if you don't.  Also, can't you rebuild the code instead of trying to fix minified code?

Comment: I don't have the option to rebuild on the server. Source maps looks like something I'm looking for. I'll look into it. Thanks

Comment: You don't necessarily need to build your production code on the server, in fact don't do that, just host it there.

Comment: Yup I actually did try that with grunt tasks in my dev machine to replace uglified files to original files. But on server only files under target folder are deployed and grunt is not packaged with that.

Comment: I've used sourceMaps from grunt config it works like a charm. It only debugs line by line in firefox where as in chrome it skips few lines..

Answer (score 3):

I use Chrome, but I'm sure FF has a similar tool:

[image: shot]

That little brackets button at the bottom of the script panel prettifies on the fly. Works whether the code is sloppy or full-on minified.

It's a good solution for quick-n-dirty, but you will run into problems if you rely on it. Source Maps are recommended. See @Kosch's answer for a decent write-up. *funny, we posted identical links*

Comment: that { } prettify button :D Haha! 
All this time, I've been debugging using chrome dev tools. Funny I never bothered about that button. Now I know it :D

Comment: I had coders' block one time and was just tinkering. ...i really thought it would do some kind of toggle with the line\column display, then it did *that* :D